# C# How do I sort the columns in a datagrid into alphabetical order?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

How do I sort the columns in a winforms datagrid control into alphabetical order?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking to sort the columns themselves, or the data rows based on the column specified? Is this asp.net or a winforms datagrid you're working with?

Comment: I think that's the columns headers, cause if it's the columns rows, that is done by default, just click the header column... am I right Scott?

Comment: Scott, can you clarify - you want to sort the *columns* in alphabetical order, or allow sorting on columns?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried binding the DataGrid to a DataTable object (instead of a view) and turning setting the "AllowSorting" property to true on the DataGrid? I believe the grid will then automatically sort the table source for you.

If not, you can always catch the event when a column header is clicked and rebuild a DataView to bind to the DataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

My items are generally lists of items in memory. With databound grids you have to sort the data at the source, not within the grid itself.

Here's the code for my list sorts. Maybe this will give you an idea for getting off the ground.

http://jspot.jerryhanel.com/2012/06/28/sort-your-databound-grid-effortlessly/